# Invalid sFTP PacketSize" and "Expected SSH_FXP_VERSION" errors on aws ec2 Canonical Ubuntu Instance

Tags: phpseclib

I Just fired up an EC2 instance using the ubuntu image provided by Canonical. Attempting to connect to it via phseclib provides the following errors:

```
Invalid SFTP packet size in phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 3041
Expected SSH_FXP_VERSION in phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php on line 495
```

The image used was: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200112

I tried the 16.04 image as well and got the same issue.

The same connection seems to work fine with other providers such as Digital Ocean, Vultr and Linode. etc. No clue what's going on with the Canonical ami at aws.

Has anyone seen this before with phpseclib and aws AMIs?

Using phpseclib 2.0.25.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the SSH logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` and then doing `echo $ssh->getLog();` after you get that error. Once you have them then post it on pastebin.com and post the link. Thanks!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I note that you posted this same issue at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1462 and you closed that issue...

Comment: @neubert - ah shoot, sorry about not responding to your prior message.  Yes, we figured out the issue.  It was, in this case, a user error with a misleading response from the server.  The program using the phpseclib library was trying to log in as "root" instead of the "ubuntu" user that is the AWS standard sudo user.